# ThreeJs: loader not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, three.js

Im trying to apply Texture to my sphere using Three.JS However, after loading the image. the content inside the function will not run. [thats my question].  i did check the networking tab in chrome and the time image is getting loaded.

Would like to know why the function is not executing.

i have used this snippet code below as my attempt.

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
var scene, camera, light, renderer, balltex;


load();

function load() {
    var loader;

    loader = new THREE.TextureLoader(new THREE.LoadingManager());

//  # # #  THIS PART HERE IS THE ISSUE # # #
    loader.load('textures/flakes.png', function(obj) {
        console.log("not running here")
        balltex = obj;
        init();
        console.log("init")
        animate();
    });
}

function init() {
    var height = 500, width = 500, bg = '#000000';
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, height/width, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(1.5, 1.5, 1.5);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    scene.add(camera);
    light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
    scene.add(light);
    var ballmat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map:    balltex
    });
    var ballgeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 0.3, 20, 20 );
    var ball = new THREE.Mesh( ballgeo , ballmat );
    scene.add(ball);
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true } );
    renderer.setClearColor(bg);
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    console.log("here",d)
    document.body.appendChild(d);
    d.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    var c = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
    c.style.width = width + 'px';
    c.style.height = height + 'px'
}

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

“I expected the function to run but it is not running for some reason.”

Editing im not using THREE.JS CDN however im using it over npm.

Thanks,

Comment: You wrote "the time image is being loaded". Did you mean the "flakes.jpg" image?

Comment: you code works for me exactly as is [if I change the url of the image](https://codepen.io/greggman/pen/JjPOXZq).

Comment: @gman Yes flakes.jpg. Interesting what could be reason for me having a white blank screen?

[link](https://ibb.co/6Y2rNrv)

Comment: Are there any messages in the JavaScript console?

Comment: No, it is blank

Comment: I was using parcel for handling to the local server creation...Now i used a different Npm package that creates a local server and is working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. You're calling `load()` before you've declared the function, so JavaScript doesn't know what you're referencing.
2. You don't need to pass a `new THREE.LoadingManager()` to the texture loader.
3. Are you sure the file `textures/flakes.png` is being loaded? Are you getting any errors in the developer console? The callback function won't be called if the file isn't at that location.

```
// 1. Define function first
function load() {
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

    // Callback is triggered if loading was successful
    loader.load('textures/flakes.png', function(obj) {
        console.log("Should work now")
        balltex = obj;
        init();
        animate();
    });
}

// 2. Call function after it's been defined
load();
```

Comment: i have tried your solution yet, no progress here is my network tab in the screenshot below.
[link](https://ibb.co/6Y2rNrv)

Comment: 1. is wrong. You can declare functions after you use them. [It's perfectly fine](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/sg7not3a/). 2. is true but irrelevant, it's perfectly fine to create a loading manager